# I am using Pandoc to create PDF book. How do I change chapter title size and alignment?

Tags: pdf, pandoc, markdown

I've already used [extsizes](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes) to change my base font to 8pt and [geometry](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins) to set my pdf output to 3.5 x 5 from markdown.

I cannot find how to override chapter title alignment (which is set to justify) or chapter title size (which is too large).

UPDATE:

I'm passing overrides through command line

```
pandoc source.md -o output.pdf --toc --toc-depth=2 -V geometry:paperheight=5in -V geometry:paperwidth=3.5in -V geometry:margin=0.25in -V geometry:bottom=0.5in -V documentclass:extarticle -V fontsize:8pt -V include-before:'\newpage' -V setlength:parskip=0pt
```

Comment: You can edit the template and use [titlesec](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) to format the section commands

Comment: Thanks @DG'. I'm a developer and have dug through the Latex template from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex but cannot determine where to change it. If you have the time, a more detailed answer might get you an accepted click.

Comment: Solution partially depends on documentsclass, I think also on your main fontsize settings, so for anybody to give you specific solution you should provide manimal example, or working material, MWE, that can be used for testing. If you want to get the job done as soon as possible, without digging deep into latex, look at titlesec doc just as DG already pointed you. If you use standard book documentclass, it should be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file with the `titlesec` settings where you can load `titlesec` with the desired options, like `center`, `tiny` and `bf`:

```
% titlesec-conf.tex
\usepackage[bf,tiny,center]{titlesec}
```

[image]

Or you can specify each sectioning level with `\titleformat`:

```
% titlesec-conf.tex
\usepackage[bf,tiny,center]{titlesec}
\titleformat
  {\chapter} 
  {\centering\bfseries\large\itshape}
  {\thechapter} {} {}
```

[image]

You need to load `titlesec-conf.tex` with `--include-in-header`:

```
$ pandoc in.md --include-in-header=titlesec-conf.tex -o out.pdf
```

---

Or you can get pandoc's latex template with `pandoc -D latex > mytemplate.latex` and add the code form above in the preamble and call pandoc with:

```
$ pandoc in.md --template=mytemplate.latex -o out.pdf
```

Comment: Just a comment from the practical side: While it works the way you suggest, outputting and tweaking the template (`-D`), or including the generated part (without headers) into a "framing" LaTeX document might be easier. It is also the way to go to use `csquotes` in pandoc-generated code without going insane. My suggestion: `main.tex` for the main document, separate `prelude.tex` for LaTeX header adjustments, `generated.tex` with contents, auto-generated from pandoc, and a `Makefile` to rule them all.